# Cargar DateTime en c# en formato dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

Buen dia! Estoy haciendo un programa de carga y muestra de peliculas, 
La clase pelicula tiene un atributo de tipo DateTime fechalanzamiento.
Mi problema es que, cuando cargo la fecha de lanzamiento en formato dd/mm/yyyy no me lo toma. Debo cargar yyyy/mm/dd y tambien me la muestra de esa forma.
Mi pregunta es si hay alguna forma no solo de que me muestre la fecha en el formato dd/mm/yyyy sino tambien que me permita cargarla en ese formato! 
Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Clase Pelicula:

```
public class Peliculas
{

    // Propiedades
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public String Nombre { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaSalida { get; set; }
    public String Pais { get; set; }
    public static int globalPeliculaId;

    // Metodos


    // Constructores
    public Peliculas()
    {
        this.Nombre = "";
        this.FechaSalida = DateTime.Now;
        this.Pais = "";
        this.Id = Interlocked.Increment(ref globalPeliculaId);
    }

    public Peliculas(String nombre, int dia, int mes, int anio, String pais)
    {
        this.Nombre = nombre;
        this.FechaSalida = new DateTime(dia, mes, anio); //Validar en Controlador que ingresen aaaa, mm y dd y no otro formato. 
        this.Pais = pais;
    }
}
```

Controlador peliculas funcion de creacion:

```
// GET: Peliculas/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
}

// POST: Peliculas/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Peliculas pelicula)
{
    try
    {
        RepoPeliculas.listado.Add(pelicula);

        return RedirectToAction("Listado");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Vista Create:

```
//porcion de codigo de la fecha)

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FechaSalida, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FechaSalida, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FechaSalida, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Buenas Maria Laura, para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por la comunidad deberias añadir el código que has probado, de esta manera evitaras que se cierre la pregunta y te podamos ayudar mejor.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta.Como bien dice @marc, necesitaríamos ver el código que estas intentando, ya que en principio un `DateTime` se puede _cargar_ con practicamente cualquier formato de fecha.

Comment: Quizás este comentario no responda directamente a tu pregunta pero te garantizo que aprenderás algo interesante con este workshop que hice: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY Saludos :D

Answer (score 2):

Bueno quiero aprovechar esta pregunta para mostrar características de ASP.Net MVC que a veces no sabemos que están pero que nos ayudan mucho. MariaLaura desea que todas las fechas sean mostradas de la forma dd/MM/yyyy, y la respuesta de Ingwvanegas no esta nada mal, pero supongamos que tenemos muchas vistas las cuales muestran fechas, esto supone tener que entrar a cada vista y modificarla para lograr lo que queremos. Pero ASP tiene una forma de hacer esto para todas las vistas. En el directorio Views/Shared creamos una carpeta de nombre DisplayTemplates y creamos dentro la vista Parcial DateTime.cshtml con el sigueinte contenido:

```
Views/Shared/DateTime.cshtml

@model DateTime
@Model.ToString("dd MMMM, yyyy")
```

de esta forma hemos definido una plantilla para nuestro helper DisplayFor de forma que si llamamos a lo siguiente:

```
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fecha)
    </td>
```

saldría:  04 December, 2017

Al igual que definimos una plantilla para DisplayFor podemos hacernos una para EditorFor. Esta vez creamos el directorio EditorTemplates en Views/Shared/ con una vista Parcial con el mismo nombre DateTime y dentro:

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<DateTime?>
@if (Model.HasValue)
{
@Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", Model.Value), new { @class = "form-control datepicker", @type = "datetime " })
}
else
{
@Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now), new { @class = "form-control datepicker", @type = "datetime" })
}
```

y en el modelo debemos poner esto:

```
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
```

al crearnos estas plantillas veremos la fecha e insertaremos la fecha en el formato que querramos en cualquier lugar de nuestra app. Espero les sea de ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Buen dia, puedes hacerlo en el codigo razor que usas facilmente usando format string

```html
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FechaSalida, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", Value=@String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyy}",  model.FechaSalida) })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FechaSalida, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FechaSalida, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Pruebalo y comentas

Comment: Hay dos comentarios aquí: 1.- El format debería de ir en el EditorFor, y no en el LabelFor 2.- El inconveniente de hacerlo así es en el post de la forma, ya que el formato no sigue la regla de fecha y te lo marca como invalido.

Comment: Ok entendido vamos a hacer un pequeño cambio

Answer (score -1):

Si solo vas a mostrar la fecha en un textbox solo tendrias que concatenar tus variables.
variables de tipo string
txt_fec.text = dia +"/"+ mes +"/"+ año

variables de tipo int
txt_fec.text = convert.ToString(dia) +"/"+ convert.ToString(mes) +"/"+ convert.ToString(año)

Answer (score -2):

Puedes emplear la función ParseExact de la clase DateTime para parsear tu fecha en el formato que deseas y para leerlo en el mismo formato puedes pasarle como parámetro a la función ToString, el mismo formato y el Proveedor de Formato de la Fecha, en nuestro caso Invariant para que omita el por defecto.

```
var dateTimeFormat = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat;
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("07/08/2014", "dd/MM/yyyy", dateTimeFormat);
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", dateTimeFormat));

//CultureInfo está en System.Globalization
```